# git branch list have "--delete", "-d", "-delete" after run git branch delete command

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm new to git, and first I cloned a remote repository doing like this:

```
git clone https://git_romote_url/repository_name.git
```

and then I created a branch locally by:

```
 git checkout -b branch_name
```

then I wanted to delete the branch branch_name, so I tried the following command:

```
 git branch –delete branch_name
 git branch –d branch_name
 git branch –-delete branch_name
```

I knew the first command is wrong (missing a horizontal line), so I tried the following two.

But after this, when I shown branches by:

```
git branch
```

The branches list showed:

```
* master
  –-delete
  –d
  –delete
```

And when I want to delete either one of "--delete", "-d" or "-delete" by:

```
git branch --delete --delete
git branch --delete -d
git branch --delete -delete
```

I got:

```
fatal: branch name required
```

I have searched the internet, but found nothing like my problems.

So, could someone please help explain why this happens and how should I handle this problem (I want to delete the three branches except master if it is ok and necessory to do this) .

Any help or hint is very appricated, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look this character: a

Now look at this character: â

They look exactly the same, don't they?  Well, no, they *don't*.  One's an ordinary lowercase A, and one is a lowercase A with a hat on it.  So they *look different*.  But they're both the letter "a", right?  (This is a rhetorical question: you're supposed to think about it, and decide whether it's right, wrong, or maybe both or neither, and under what conditions.)

Now, look at this character: -

Then look at this one: –

They are the same, aren't they?  Or *are* they?  Let me line up a bunch of them:

-----
    –––––

There are five dashes on each line.  Can you see that they are different?  Here they are again but in fixed-width computer font:

```
-----
–––––
```

Do they look the same, or do they look different?  (On my screen, the en-dash characters in the fixed-width font merge to make a solid line, while the hyphens don't so that there are five separate hyphens instead of one solid line.  In the variable-pitch font, the en-dashes are a bit longer than the hyphens, but shorter than em-dashes: they don't merge, but they come close.)

Now, luckily for us, you cut-and-pasted your branch names, so we can actually tell what Unicode characters these are.  Your branch named `–-delete` is not `--delete` (two dashes), it's en-dash, dash, d, e, l, e, t, e.  To type this en-dash character on my Mac keyboard, I use the option key, <kbd>⌥</kbd>, plus the <kbd>-</kbd> key.  (Using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> gets an em-dash.)

Your `–d` and `–delete` branch names are very similar: both start with an en-dash.  Find out how to *type in* an en-dash, and use that to run `git branch -d` to delete them.  For more about en-dash and em-dash, see https://proofed.com/writing-tips/how-to-type-an-en-dash-and-em-dash-on-windows-and-mac-devices/ for instance.

Comment: Really thanks very very much, I think maybe I would never find the reason if you haven't told me. The en-dash looks so similar to dash that I can't find the difference. Actually, I even don't know how I typed en-dash when I tried to delete branch_name (Because these en-dash begining branches must be created when I tried to delete branch_name because of error typing). I can only use copy-and-paste method to finally  get the correct name of the three error created branches to be deleted. By the way, my platform is Windows.